# how to use the "SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS" Parameters

Tags: windows, winapi

I am learning Win32 API programming. I read this paragraph, it says:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa

> SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS
>
> Enables or disables the Mouse Trails feature, which improves the visibility of mouse cursor movements by briefly showing a trail of cursors and quickly erasing them.
>
> To disable the feature, set the uiParam parameter to zero or 1. To enable the feature, set uiParam to a value greater than 1 to indicate the number of cursors drawn in the trail.
>
> Windows 2000: This parameter is not supported.

I tried to write the following code:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    //SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS, NULL,(PVOID)10, 0);
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS, NULL,(PVOID)0, 0);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Can anyone tell me how this macro works? I couldn't find an example on the Internet, so I am asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation again more carefully:

> To disable the feature, set the **uiParam** parameter to zero or 1. To enable the feature, set **uiParam** to a value greater than 1 to indicate the number of cursors drawn in the trail.

Look at the declaration of the function:

```c
BOOL SystemParametersInfoA(
    UINT uiAction,
    UINT uiParam,
    PVOID pvParam,
    UINT fWinIni
);
```

Your code is setting the `uiParam` parameter to 0 (disabling the feature), and setting the `pvParam` parameter to the cursor count (which is ignored).

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    UINT cursorCount = ...;
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS, cursorCount, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

> I couldn't find an example on the Internet

Really? When I enter *just* SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS by itself into Google, literally the 1st link returned contains an example:

http://ntcoder.com/bab/tag/spi_setmousetrails/

> SystemParametersInfo is a powerful function which does and retrieves whole lot of things related to windows general behavior for eg: turning on and off certain features like mouse trails which we normally do via control panel->main.cpl
>
> Look up MSDN for more information on SystemParametersInfo. I’ll just show a demo on how to turn on and off mouse trails…
>
> ```c
> // Turn on mouse trails, showing 10 cursors drawn in the trail
> SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS, 10, 0, 0 );
> // Turn off mouse trails, set trail count to 1 or zero to disable trails
> SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS, 1, 0, 0 );
> ```

Comment: thanks,I have search "SystemParametersInfo SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS"but find little thing

I'm not sure if the "show the track of the mouse" mentioned here is "like a comet dragging its tail" as I understand it, so I didn't find such examples on Google.
May I ask which keyword you used to search, thank you, I will read the document a little more carefully to prevent being affected by the wrong ideas in other places.

Comment: @ffxxee "*I'm not sure if the "show the track of the mouse" mentioned here is "like a comet dragging its tail" as I understand it*" - yes, it is. "*so I didn't find such examples on Google. May I ask which keyword you used to search*" - as I stated in my answer, I searched for SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS by itself.